# IE problem - Unwanted margin around images

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin

http://www.wedevents.com.au/index.asp

No problem in FF but in IE there are some unwanted white margins appearing around the images in the top and bottom menu.

Any ideas on how to remove the unwanted margin?

HTML:

```
<ul class="topnav">
<li>
    <a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/index.asp"> 
    <img src="/images/menu_home.gif" name="home" onMouseOver="over(0)" onMouseOut="out(0)" alt="Home" /></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/about.asp"> 
    <img src="/images/menu_about.gif" name="about" onMouseOver="over(1)" onMouseOut="out(1)" alt="About" /></a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
ul.topnav {
list-style: none;
padding: 0 85px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 630px;
height: 36px;
background: #b09a27;
font-size: medium;
text-align: left;
}
ul.topnav li {
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}
ul.topnav li a{
padding: 0;
color: #fff;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no margin or padding on the image. The user agent style is defaulting to putting a border around the image. Set `border: 0;` on the image. Also see the other answer for reset.css to prevent this sort of thing in the future.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea why the margin-bottom: 40px in my footer wrapper is being ignored in IE? None of the other pages are effected, but the homepage is unique in that it doesn't have that logo and bg image at the bottom.

Comment: @Rick, I'd open another question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a reset.css  Here's one I like http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Great tip. I'll keep a shortcut to it for when I need it.